# jqGrid edit modal AJAX?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a table with data, which is taken from the server. The table shows only two  column. But to edit the data I will have other columns. In other words, I need to change colmodel on edit modal window? How can I do that?
I use free jqGrid last version. I found example navGrid.

[Simple](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid2.htm)

How get from server (AJAX) other columns for edit?

Comment: Could you describe more exactly what you need? You can't "change `colModel` on edit modal window", but you can customize the content of Editing form and the information which will be sand to the server. You wrote: "to edit the data I will have other columns". Do you want to display the information in Edit form? Do you want to allow the use to edit the hidden columns? Do you want not display the information, but just to send it together with edited row? It would be better to explain all on example. Could you add the `colModel` which you use (at least one non-hidden column and one hidden)?

Comment: display the information in Edit form addition data from AJAX and edit this data

Answer (score 0):

You can specify

```js
editrules: { edithidden: true }
```

additionally to `hidden: true` in the columns which you want to allow to edit.

For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClickEditHidden.htm) have hidden column `tax` which can be editing using form editing. You can start editing in the demo in three ways: double-click on the row, click on the edit button in the row and selection of the row and then click on the edit button in the navigator bar of the pager.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to not use a hidden field? I have too much additional data that is not in the table, and it can affect performance

Comment: @kpoLP: There are many options, which are oriented on different scenarios. It's very difficult to recommend you someone if you don't posted almost nothing about what you do. How many items and fields you have? **Do you use paging of data? Do you tried the usage hidden columns and you have some performance problems?** It has really no sense to try to reduce displaying and editing of the grid (without the time of the loading the data from the server, which is independent from jqGrid) from 50ms to 10 ms, but one should invert the time to reduce 5000ms to 100ms.

Comment: **I do not use pagination for some reason**.I have 1k records and 7 fields. However, to edit fields will be 20. It makes no sense to add another 13 fields hidden. Request for data editing is a little slower. This extra data in the table. And I think the load on the drawing in DOM will be significant in a large number of records.

Comment: Can add additional fields to the window for editing? But I do not know how to do it

Comment: I have an idea, you can do so. The form for editing to create another table instead of the standard data.

Comment: @kpoLP: If you have an interest to improve the performance of the application you should start with the usage of **paging**. The filling of 1K record take more as 99% of the time. The user can see about 25 rows, but you fill 1000 rows instead. You can use `loadonce: true` for example and *local* paging of data. Try [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm), which uses 40000 rows, 13 columns and 20 rows in page. Test filling the grid, paging, sorting, filtering.

Comment: @kpoLP: You will see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) which uses only 4000 rows and you see that it works even more better. Compare the results with the performance of your current grid. You will see that **paging is the bottleneck of your application**. You can invest much time and make many other optimizations, but one should start always with  optimization of the bottleneck.